# Appsettings.json How does one check to see what environment is being used?

Tags: asp.net-core

If one has a running .net core web app and there are multiple appsettings.json files in the root, how can you tell what environmentname is set to?  I guess one way is to write your own utility or status page where you use code to write out the value of this variable.  Is there another way?

Instead of using some sort of transform as in the case with web.config files, you now generally deploy all the environment-specific appsettings files, and let the app determine the value of the environment.  This seems kinda confusing, in that you no longer can simply look at a config file and know what settings the app is using.

Comment: "ASP.NET Core reads the environment variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT at app startup and stores the value in IHostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName." Its in the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: Just wanted to mention, if that variable is not set it will default to 'Production'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the value of [`IHostingEnvironment.Environment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.ihostingenvironment.environmentname?view=aspnetcore-3.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_IHostingEnvironment_EnvironmentName) as William suggested in the comments, but a better approach would be to call either [`IHostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.hostingenvironmentextensions.isdevelopment?view=aspnetcore-3.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_HostingEnvironmentExtensions_IsDevelopment_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_IHostingEnvironment_) or [`IHostingEnvironment.IsEnvironment()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.hostingenvironmentextensions.isenvironment?view=aspnetcore-3.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_HostingEnvironmentExtensions_IsEnvironment_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_IHostingEnvironment_System_String_) and it will do the name checking for you.

Methods for checking for production ([`IHostingEnvironment.IsProduction()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.hostingenvironmentextensions.isproduction?view=aspnetcore-3.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_HostingEnvironmentExtensions_IsProduction_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_IHostingEnvironment_)) and staging ([`IHostingEnvirionment.IsStaging()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.hostingenvironmentextensions.isstaging?view=aspnetcore-3.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_HostingEnvironmentExtensions_IsStaging_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_IHostingEnvironment_)) exist as well.